# When veryfying login credentials what is the appropriate response if given username does not exist?

Tags: php, mysql, security, authentication

For example someone tries to log in with the name "Bob" but there is no Bob in the database. Should the user be notified there is no Bob or should should the program simply say "authentication failed" (I noticed Gmail does this)? This is partly a usability question and partly an efficiency question. As it is now the program queries the database to see if the given username exists and if it does then it queries the database again to find the password hash for the same username (redundant).

```
//$link is the link to the database storing passwords/usernames
if(userNameExists($uName, $link))
{
    if(passwordCorrect($uName, $pass, $link))
        echo 'log in successful!';
    else
        echo 'can\'t log in';
}
else
{
    echo 'username doesn\'t exist!';
}

/*This function checks to see if the username exists
INPUT: the userName to check for and a link to the database
OUTPUT: true if username exists
*/
function userNameExists($userName, $link)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `userid`
                        FROM `login`
                        WHERE `userid` = \''.$userName.'\' LIMIT 1');//need to look into uses of backticks, single quotes, double quotes
    return mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1;
}

/*This function checks the password for a given username
INPUT: the userName and password the user entered, and a link to the database
OUTPUT: true if the given password matches the one in the database
*/
function passwordCorrect($userName, $givenPassword, $link)
{
    $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `password`
                        FROM `login`
                        WHERE userid = \''.$userName.'\' LIMIT 1');
    $retrievedPassword = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if(password_verify($givenPassword, $retrievedPassword['password']))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Should I instead only use `passwordCorrect()` and if `mysqli_query()` returns false this implies the username does not exist (admittedly I don't like these solutions because it could mean something else has gone wrong, doesn't it?)?

Comment: You should being doing one query which gets both the username and password hash.

Comment: Same error for both invalid username and for invalid password, else a brute force hacker can know when he's used a valid username and then only needs to guess a password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *not provide details* why the login failed (user does not exists or password is wrong), as this increases security. Unless usernames are visible when one is not logged in (which is actually insecure and should not be the case..!)

Advantage is that you indeed can use a single query to get the hash for the given username. If you do not get a result, the username is wrong (and the login failed), otherwise you can (directly) check the hash (to see if the password is wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking there are two basic points to this story that you can consider

1. Providing specific information may improve usability because the user then knows what piece of information he provided was erroneous
2. But providing specific information also allows for potential abuse. If you specifically return if a username did not exist, the opposite might alert a hacker that a username ***does*** exist and he may use that information to more effectively use brute force techniques to crack logins

What best suits your situation will always be a trade off but often it is advised to omit specific information for the aforementioned security reasons